# Can a method doSomething(vector<ParentClass>) act differently depending on what kind of vector<ChildClass> is passed as argument?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

While taking an introductory class on C++ I came to ponder whether the following would be possible:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Parent {};
class ChildA : public Parent {};
class ChildB : public Parent {};

void doSomething(vector<Parent> v){
  if (v is of type vector<ChildA>) ...
  else if (v is of type vector<ChildB>) ...
}

int main(void){
  vector<ChildA> a;
  vector<ChildB> b;
  doSomething(a);
  doSomething(b);
  return 0;
}
```

In a nutshell, the method `doSomething()`, which I wish to define only once, would act differently depending on whether the input vector has elements of type `ChildA` or `ChildB`. As of now I face two problems:

1. A method that would take a `Parent` as an argument would allow me to pass `ChildA` as an argument as well, yet this is not the case once vectors are used i.e. I get the error

`no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<ChildA, std::allocator<ChildA>>" to "std::vector<Parent, std::allocator<Parent>>" exists`

2. This problem isn't grave, but I'm currently findind the type of `v` by means of the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c), yielding types such as e.g. `St6vectorI6ChildASaIS0_EE`, which doesn't seem elegant. On the other hand, I can't seem to wrap my head around posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399820/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-the-elements-in-a-vector), as they deal with templates, which I know not how to use.

Comment: That just won't work. The vector types are different (as the compiler says) and you're getting into [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) issues.You're better of making the classes polymorphic and call functions in the objects.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with

```
void doSomething(vector<Parent> v){
  if (v is of type vector<ChildA>) ...
  else if (v is of type vector<ChildB>) ...
}
```

is that the answer to both tests is `false`. The argument `v` is a `vector<Parent>`, as the declaration says.

You'd need

```
template< typename Elem>
void doSomething(vector<Elem> v){
  if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<ChildA, Elem>) ...
  else if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<ChildB, Elem>) ...
}
```

Now you have the actual `Elem` type and can check that. But plain overloading might be even easier:

```
void doSomething(vector<childA> v){
 // v is of type vector<ChildA>) ...
}
void doSomething(vector<childB> v){
 // v is of type vector<ChildB>) ...
}
private:
void helper(Parent& elem){
 // shared helper for doSomething overloads
}
```

Comment: I would advice against oveloading based on `vector<Type>`. Just use a constrained template and use the overloaded function inside the vector loop. See the overload example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on dynamic polymorphism, or static polymorphism or a mixture of both to achieve this.

Dynamic polymorphism:

```
void do_something(const vector<Parent*>& vec) {
    for (auto* p : vec) 
        p->call_virtual_function();
}
```

The vector in this case needs to contain (smart)pointers to objects to avoid slicing.

Overload resolution:

```
void overloaded_function(const Child1& ch) { }
void overloaded_function(const Child2& ch) { }

template<class Type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Parent, Type>, int> = 0> // or c++20 concepts
void do_something(const vector<Type>& vec) {
    for (auto& el : vec)
        call_overloaded_function(el);
}
```

In this case the vector must be a vector of type `Child1` or `Child2` to work, but note that the vector does not need to contain pointers in this case. This does not rely on dynamic polymorphism.

You can also use `dynamic_cast` but this might be seen as bad code:

```
void do_something_single(const Parent* p)
{
    if (auto* c = dynamic_cast<const Child1*>(p)) {
        // do something with c as Child1
    } else if (auto* c = dynamic_cast<const Child2*>(p)) {
        // do something with c as Child2
    } else ...
}

void do_something(const vector<Parent*>& vec) {
    for (auto*p : vec) {
        do_something_single(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not possible. A `std::vector<Parent>` and a `std::vector<ChildA>` have as much in common as `std::vector<foo>` and `std::vector<bar>`: almost nothing. They are instantiation of the same template, but that means less than you might expect, in particular `std::vector<ChildA>` and `std::vector<ChildB>` have no common base class.

You need pointers or references for polymorphism. Maybe you actually want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>` that can store pointers to either of your three types.

For vectors of objects you can make the function a function template:

```
 template <typename T>
 void doSomething(std::vector<T> v){ /*...*/ }
```

However, if you want `doSomething` to do something different depending on the type, then there is little gain in doing that and you can simply use overloads:

```
 void doSomething(std::vector<ChildA>) { /*...*/ }
 void doSomething(std::vector<ChildB>) { /*...*/ }
```

---

> A method that would take a `Parent` as an argument would allow me to pass `ChildA` as an argument as well, [...]

Yes, but no. A method `void foo(Parent)` takes only a `Parent` object as argument. If you pass it a `ChildA` then the part of the derived class is sliced off and only a `Parent` is passed to the function. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). You need pointers or references for polymorphism.